# Is the information captured by Doc2Vec a subset of the information captured by BERT?

Tags: vector, projection, bert-language-model, doc2vec

Both Doc2Vec and BERT are NLP models used to create vectors for text. The original BERT model maintained a vector of 768, while the original Doc2Vec model maintained a vector of size 300.  Would it be reasonable to assume that all the information captured by D2V is a subset of information captured by BERT?

I ask, because I want to think about how to compare differences in representations for a set of sentences between models. I am thinking I could project the BERT vectors into a D2V subspace and compare those vectors to the D2V vectors for the same sentence, but this relies on the assumption that the subspace I'm projecting the BERT vectors into is actually comparable (i.e., the same type of information) to the D2V space.

The objective functions, while different, are quite similar. The Cloze task for BERT and the next word prediction for D2V are both trying to create associations between a word and its surrounding words. BERT can look bidirectionally, while D2V can only look at a window and moves from the left to the right of a sentence. The same objective function doesn't necessarily mean that they're capturing the same information, but it seems in which the way D2V does it (the covariates it uses) are a subset of the covariates used by BERT.

Interested to hear other people's thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume by `Doc2Vec` you mean the "Paragraph Vector" algorithm, which is often called `Doc2Vec` (including in libraries like Python Gensim).

That `Doc2Vec` is closely related to word2vec: it's essentially word2vec with a synthetic floating pseudoword vector over the entire text. It models texts via a shallow network that can't really consider word-order, or the composite-meaning of word runs, *except* in a very general 'nearness' sense.

So, a `Doc2Vec` model will not generate realistic/grammatical completions/summaries from vectors (except perhaps in very-limited single-word tests).

What info `Doc2Vec` most captures can be somewhat influenced by parameter choices, especially choice-of-mode and `window` (in modes where that matters, like when co-training word-vectors).

BERT is a far deeper model with more internal layers and a larger default dimensionality of text-representations. Its training mechanisms give it the potential to differentiate between significant word-orderings – and thus be sensitive to grammar and composite phrases beyond what `Doc2Vec` can learn. It can generate plausible multi-word completions/summarizations.

You could certainly train a 768-dimension `Doc2Vec` model on the same texts as a BERT model & compare the results. The resulting summary text-vectors, from the 2 models, would likely perform quite differently on key tasks. If you need to detect subtle shifts in meaning in short texts – things like the reversal of menaing from the insert of a single 'not' – I'd expect the BERT model to dominate (if sufficiently trained). On broader tasks less-sensitive to grammar like topic-classification, the `Doc2Vec` model might be competitive, or (given its simplicity) attractive in its ability to achieve certain targets with far less data or quicker training.

So, it'd be improper to assume that what `Doc2Vec` captures is a proper subset of what BERT does.

You could try learning a mapping from one model to the other (possibly including dimensionality-reduction), as there are surely many consistent correlations between the trained coordinate-spaces. But the act of creating such a mapping requires starting assumptions that certain vectors "should" line-up, or be in similar configurations.

If trying to understand what's unique/valuable across the two options, it's likely better to compare how the models rank a text's neighbors – do certain kinds of similarities dominate in one or the other? Or, try both as inputs to downstream classification/info-retrieval tasks, and see where they each shine.

(With sufficient data & training time, I'd expect BERT as the more-sophisticated model to usually provide better results – especially if it's also allotted a larger representation. But for some tasks, and limited data/compute/time resources, `Doc2Vec` might shine.

Comment: Really appreciate your response. My initial thinking was to find the basis vectors of a subspace in the BERT world that matches the dimensions of the traditional D2V (Paragraph Vector) algorithm. This would rely on the assumption that what information D2V learns about the high dimensional object "language" is a subset of the information set also gathered by BERT. Given the objective functions are similar and the features used in D2V appear to be a subset of BERT, this seems like a reasonable assumption.

The alternative is to use a prediction task to project into a comparable space.

Comment: It seems possible to support the assumption by looking at the behavior of neighbors in the subspace the BERT vectors would be projected into and the D2V representations. For example, if we compared the distance between "King" and "Queen" in the BERT subspace with the distance of the same words in the D2V vector space, and they were similar, it would lend support that the subspaces are representing similar information.

Comment: I'd be concerned that in devising the projection, you'd be assuming your conclusion: forcing correlations based on the process of extracting basis-vectors/translations, using certain paired-relations as targets. And the absolute distances in these models can be highly sensitive to training parameters, and especially choice-of-dimensions. *Relative* distances/neighbor-ranks are far more reflective of the models' value (or not). (Between a 50d or 300d or 768d word2vec model, `'king'` & `'queen'` may always be in each others' closest neighbors - but the raw distances will be wildly different.)